# How to cross-compile with CMake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I currently have a Visual Studio Code project, I'm running my main.cpp with CMake and everything works fine. I can also run my program from a command terminal under Ubuntu. I also managed to cross-compile a simple program but the problem is that my main.cpp is in a big project.
My question is, is there a simple way to cross-compile my main.cpp for an ARM architecture (I am on x64-64).
I have heard about toolchains but the examples don't really correspond to my case so I write this question. And i dont know how to edit my CMakeLists.txt in order to do this.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(hash VERSION 0.1.0)



FILE(GLOB srcSources src/*.cpp)


find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)


add_executable(hash
${srcSources}
)

target_link_libraries(hash Qt5::Core)



target_include_directories(hash PUBLIC
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"

)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you say that toolchain files don't correspond to your case?

Comment: @xev sorry if I explained wrong, I mean I dont know how to write these toolchain files and no one that I had copy/paste has worked. That's why I dont know what to do at this point

Comment: What cross-compiler are you using?

Comment: @xev i'm using gcc/g++

Comment: The actual name of the cross-compiler, something like:
arm-none-eabi-gcc.

gcc itself isn't a cross-compiler, unlike clang where you can pass a target option

Comment: @xev oh sure my bad, i'm using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating a CMake toolchain file like, you can call it my_toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX arm-linux-gnueabi-)
execute_process(
  COMMAND which ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE BINUTILS_PATH
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

get_filename_component(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR ${BINUTILS_PATH} DIRECTORY)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/../arm-linux-gnueabi)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${BINUTILS_PATH})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Then use it to invoke CMake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="my_toolchain.cmake" -S. -Bbin
```

Of course you need Qt-core to be installed in the /lib path in your cross-compiler's sysroot

Comment: I have my folder project that contains folders "build", "src", "include" and file CMakeLists.txt . I added my_toolchain.cmake in the folder project, am I right?. My main.cpp is in the folder src and I tried to do the command in the path Desktop/project, should I do it in Desktop/project/build ?
Sorry for these questions I'm trying to understand well

Comment: You do it like you usually build your project with CMake, except that you add `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/path/to/my_toolchain.cmake". Make sure you have a correct Qt Core installed for your architecture

Comment: When i do this I have this error (and yes qt is installed):
```
CMake Error at my_toolchain.cmake:11 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error at my_toolchain.cmake:11 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bi/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

Comment: Here is the second part of the error:
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

Comment: Can you update the file, I changed the contents

Comment: Sure, here is the new message (part 1):

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
CMake Error at my_toolchain.cmake:11 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bi/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files

Comment: part 2:
CMake Error at /home/nomadea/Bureau/qthash/build/my_toolchain.cmake:11 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/nomadea/Bureau/qthash/build/bi/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  /home/nomadea/Bureau/qthash/build/bi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:44 (try_compile):
  Failed to configure test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

Comment: Don't be sorry ! Here is the new error :

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
 It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/nomadea/Bureau/qthash/build/bi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Comment: I guess this is the problem no ? :

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

At the end I have this too:

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

Comment: How did you get the compiler?

Comment: I did these commands:

Sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi 
Sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi 

With this I'm able to compile a simple program "hello.cpp" that i've tested before.
But I think the problem for me is the structure of the project maybe I should regroup all in the same folder i dont know :/

Comment: I've added: ```set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)``` To the file, can you test the new updated version?

Comment: Okay, now I have this but Qt is installed on my machine (i checked with sudo apt-get install qt5-default) :

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

Comment: Yeah you need Qt that's built for arm-linux-gnueabi. Any library you use should also be built for arm-linux-gnueabi. Your options are to build Qt yourself or somehow get a version of Qt that's built for arm-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: I'm looking for it, for the moment I didn't find the answer but thank you for your help it's really helpful !